# Bootstrap 4 vertical align a list-group with some text and dropdown

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am quite new to Bootstrap 4. I am struggling to vertically align some elements on a list-group. It consists on some text on the left side and a dropdown on the right.

```
<div class="dashboard-blocks">
  <ul class="list-group ">
    <li class="dashboard-block list-group-item">
      <span class="align-middle">Write Article/s</span>
      <span class="btn-group float-right">
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
          data-toggle="dropdown"
          aria-haspopup="true"
          aria-expanded="false"
        >
          ACTION
        </button>
        <span class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
          <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">
            Another action
          </button>
          <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">
            Something else here
          </button>
        </span>
      </span>
    </li>
```

On the CSS side I am just applying some styling to the font/colors/borders plus:

```
.dashboard-block {
 ...
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
...
  padding: 25px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

As you can see here "Write Article" is not vertically aligned:
[image: list-group with misalignment]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use flex utility. Due to .float-right it is not allowing to vertically center the span element.

```
<div class="dashboard-blocks">
    <ul class="list-group ">
        <li class="dashboard-block list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
          <span class="align-middle">Write Article/s</span>
          <span class="btn-group">
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
              data-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-haspopup="true"
              aria-expanded="false"
            >
              ACTION
            </button>

          </span>
        </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

Things to do:

1. Add classes to `<li>` : **.d-flex, .justify-content-between,
   .align-items-center**
2. Remove **.align-middle** and **.float-right** classes from span(not required).

Sample JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/srijan1709/apbmgde2/13/

Bootstrap 4 Flex Utility: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Answer (score 1):

You juste need to add this CSS style to your SPAN

```
vertical-align:middle;
```

good luck!